# I need to find the synonyms for a given word from a sentence. For an example

Tags: python, synonym

I need to find the synonyms for a given word. For an example
list1 = ['happy life']

In Python code, by using NLTK library, i got single word synonyms, but I need synonyms of two or more than two words together.

Comment: Besides `happy life` what other word pairs are you trying to obtain synonyms for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be using a split method to split the two words into single words, then running that against the library that you're using.
An example would be like the one below:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
synonyms = []
antonyms = []
input = "happy life"

input = input.split()

dictSynonyms = {}


for word in input:
    for syn in wordnet.synsets(word):
        for l in syn.lemmas():
            dictSynonyms[l.name()] = word
```